# getting Greendao to return object on insertOrUpdate?

Tags: greendao

When using the insertOrUpdate method in Greendao, is it possible to return the inserted object.  I basically want to get at the newly created key.

I see references to rowId but i don't think that is going to help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the returned `rowId` to get the entity with: `EntityDao.loadByRowId(rowId)`. From the entity you can then get the key with `EntityDao.getKey(entity)`.